# Detect from the Application class the reason of the start

Tags: android-intent, android

I have a Application implementation where I do some heavy tasks in the background, which might been better in a service but this does not matter for this question.

However I have the problem that I need to know why the Application was started. Like through a normal intent (where the intent is also interesting but this is optional) or if the app is only stated for a backup or recovery operation. In the last case I can omit much things I would need for a normal start.

**How can I detect why my Application implementation was started (Intent vs. backup/recovery)?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However I have the problem that I need to know why the Application was started

That is not possible, sorry. Whatever is started can then *tell* the `Application` why it was started, but the `Application` has no great way of determining that independently, any more than would any other singleton.

> I have a Application implementation where I do some heavy tasks in the background, which might been better in a service but this does not matter for this question.

Actually, IMHO, it does. The `Application` object is created in every process, just after any of your `ContentProvider`s (if any). I find it disturbing that you would start doing "some heavy tasks" just because the process starts, while the process is starting. In many cases, that's a very important time for your UX, and tying up gobs of CPU time right at that moment is not a good idea.

Having this work be done by a service, on the other hand, gives you flexibility on timing. It also serves as a marker to the OS that you are doing these "heavy tasks", without which Android can terminate your process at will once it is no longer in the foreground.

Comment: Okay that confirms my research. I choose to do that stuff in application because I wanted to be sure that this things are done or better not `null` when I need them. Now I have two use cases where this is not what I want. So I will check how much work it is to move that code to a service.

Comment: @rekire: "I choose to do that stuff in application because I wanted to be sure that this things are done or better not null when I need them" -- if the tasks are heavy, there is no guarantee that they'd be done anyway. This is what leads to those lovely "it's a timing thing" bugs. :-)

Comment: Please correct me, but if I do something in onCreate of the Application no activities will start until onCreate is done. So far it seems to be guaranteed that no activity is started at a unexcepted state.

Comment: @rekire: "but if I do something in onCreate of the Application no activities will start until onCreate is done" -- and if you spend more than a millisecond in `onCreate()` (of `Application`, or `Activity`, or `Service`), you're doing it wrong. "Heavy tasks" to me implied that you are spawning a background thread; if you are spending lots of time on the main application thread, you are blocking the UI from showing. If needed, show the UI, then populate it when the data is loaded from the background.